# Wordpress, WooCommerce - save product is very slow

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Some products are extremely slow to save (30 sec)

here is a screen shot from the profiler:

[image]

I turn on Slow Query log in mysql, and found this query:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ID )
FROM wpmf_posts p
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT object_id
FROM wpmf_term_relationships
WHERE term_taxonomy_id
IN ( 7 )
) AS exclude_join ON exclude_join.object_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN (

SELECT object_id
FROM wpmf_term_relationships
INNER JOIN wpmf_term_taxonomy
USING ( term_taxonomy_id )
WHERE term_id
IN ( 4246, 4247, 4254, 4257, 4263, 4280, 4290, 4335, 4375, 4397, 4486, 5114 )
) AS include_join ON include_join.object_id = p.ID
WHERE 1 =1
AND p.post_status =  'publish'
AND p.post_type =  'product'
AND exclude_join.object_id IS NULL
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

which returns 4799, and takes 27 sec:

```
# Time: 190127  8:38:29
# User@Host: lfytcoil_uprdb[lfytcoil_uprdb] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 27.287704  Lock_time: 0.000076 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 483196982
```

Any idea what is the purpose of this query?

This is `wpmf_term_taxonomy` with id
`product_visibility`

The `count` shows 
31234

This is a WooCommerce site with 10717 products,

I suspect that there too many products for WooCommerce to handle.

NOTE: after running `delete FROM`wpmf_term_relationships`where`term_taxonomy_id`= 7` which deleted 31234, the save take only 2 sec
My question:

1. Is WooCommerce not able to handle 10717 products?
2. Is there a way to somehow improve the `save`?
   e.g. by disabling this query? or by caching the result? or improve the DB structure? or install some smart modules?
3. I notice the call to `wp_update_term_count`, it seems that if I disable this call, then the problem will be solved, what could be the side effects of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*NOTE: My previous answer is wrong*

I found you can defer term count by adding

```
    wp_defer_term_counting(true);
```

before the `save` operation (i.e. in the beginning of the script)

Than do

```
    wp_defer_term_counting(false);
```

at the end of the script,
which also run the term count

Answer (score 0):

The solution is explain in this issue:

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14900

you should replace the file `includes/wc-term-functions.php`

with this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/ec489ce1a0c9030a73080ada28f25162f441dfdb/includes/wc-term-functions.php

Comment: Note: I just found that on some products this solution still takes 30 sec